# target node-webkit browser using jquery

Tags: jquery, function, webkit, target, node-webkit

I have a node-webkit app and am wondering if there is a way to target just node-webkit specifically? I need to run some functions only if the client browser is node-webkit.

Thanks

Comment: if its a node-webkit app, how is ever *not* going to be a node-webkit browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just been doing this:

```
//detect node-webkit
var isNodeWebkit = (typeof process == "object");

if (isNodeWebkit)
{
    console.log( 'in node-webkit v' + process.versions['node-webkit']);
      //node webkit specific code
}
```

ie, checking if 'process' is a valid object reference.

Comment: I've been looking for this for a while now, I love you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can tell it by testing `process.versions['node-webkit']`.

Answer (score 0):

For 'http://' protocol apps i came with a hack solution: 
 0===navigator.plugins.length?!0:!1;

Answer (score 0):

following logic is most precise:

```
var isNode = (typeof process !== "undefined" && typeof require !== "undefined");
var isNodeWebkit = false;
if (isNode) {
  try {
    isNodeWebkit = (typeof require('nw.gui') !== "undefined");
  } catch(e) {
    isNodeWebkit = false;
  }
}
```

referred from: https://videlais.com/2014/08/23/lessons-learned-from-detecting-node-webkit/, thanks to the author:)